# I cannot access tablib attribute into java code

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, taglib

I am writing JSP page to request 'guest book' report and I have a country list to display at combobox html tag, as shown below:

```
<select id="from" name="from" style="width: 120px; height:30px; padding:0">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <jsp:useBean id="estados" scope="page" class="system.web.beans.EstadoListBean"/>
                        <c:forEach items="${estados.getArrayList}" varStatus="list" var="est">
                            <%
                                String temp = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("est");
                                String value[] = temp.split(";");
                                out.print("<option value='");
                                out.print(value[1]);
                                out.print("'>");
                                out.print(value[0]);
                                out.print("</option>");
                            %>
                        </select>
                        </c:forEach>
```

When I will test at my localhost tomcat 9.0, I get this error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/guestbook.jsp] at line [31]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from     fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/guestbook.jsp] at line [31]

28:                             <select id="from" name="from" style="width: 120px; height:30px; padding:0">
29:                                 <option value="">Selecione</option>
30:                             <jsp:useBean id="estados" scope="page" class="system.web.beans.EstadoListBean"/>
31:                             <c:forEach items="${estados.getArrayList}" varStatus="list" var="est">
32:                                 <%
33:                                     String temp = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("est");
34:                                     String value[] = temp.split(";");


Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:610)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /guestbook.jsp(31,28) '${estados.getArrayList}' Property [getArrayList] not found on type     [system.web.beans.EstadoListBean]
    org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:136)
    org.apache.jsp.guestbook_jsp._jspService(guestbook_jsp.java:171)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

At my class EstadoListBean.java is here:

```
package system.web.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author oliveira
 */
public class EstadoListBean implements Serializable{
    private String list [] = {    "São Paulo"
    ,"Rio de Janeiro"
    ,"Amazonas"
    ,"Alagoas"
    ,"Amapá"
    ,"Bahía"
    ,"Brasília"
    ,"Ceará"
    ,"Espírito Santo"
    ,"Goiás"
    ,"Maranhão"
    ,"Mato Grosso"
    ,"Mato Grosso do Sul"
    ,"Minas Gerais"
    ,"Pará"
    ,"Paraíba"
    ,"Paraná"
    ,"Pernambuco"
    ,"Piauí"
    ,"Rio Grande do Norte"
    ,"Rio Grande do Sul"
    ,"Roraima"
    ,"Rondônia"
    ,"Santa Catarina"
    ,"Tocamtins"};
    
    private String abrev[] = {
    "SP",
    "RJ",
    "AM",
    "AL",
    "AP",
    "BH",
    "BSB",
    "CE",
    "ES",
    "GO",
    "MA",
    "MT",
    "MS",
    "MG",
    "PA",
    "PB",
    "PN",
    "PE",
    "PI",
    "RN",
    "RS",
    "RR",
    "RO",
    "SC",
    "TO"};

    public EstadoListBean () {
        
    }
    /**
     * @return the list
     */
    public String[] getList() {
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * @param list the list to set
     */
    public void setList(String[] list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    /**
     * @return the abrev
     */
    public String[] getAbrev() {
        return abrev;
    }

    /**
     * @param abrev the abrev to set
     */
    public void setAbrev(String[] abrev) {
        this.abrev = abrev;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.list.length;
    }
    
    public String getByIndex (int idx) {
        return this.list[idx];
    }
    
    public String getSiglaByIndex (int idx) {
        return this.abrev[idx];
    }
    
    public List getArrayList() {
        ArrayList <String>ret = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int idx = 0; idx < list.length; idx++) {
            String str = list[idx] + ";" + abrev[idx];
            ret.add(str);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I using Apache Tomcat 9.0  JSTL 1.2.6

So, I don't understand what happens !??

Comment: <c:forEach items="${estados.list}" var="state">
    ${state}
</c:forEach>          Please tell us what that prints. ( First remove the <c:forEach> code that you posted at the top of your question.)

Comment: I cannot do it. State attribute is a composite String that I want split in two variables.

Comment: Did you try what I posted?  In my code line, "list" refers to the String array named list in your bean.  I am suggesting that you start with a simple display and afterwards we can proceed to the more complicated case of the composite.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The key here is: I want get a String into ListArray and split it into 2 variables, showing it into 2 differents HTML tags (one for value attribute and other to showed string into Select/Option tags).